# Returning the intermediate result of calculations of function in java

Tags: java, android

Is it possible? the calcuations in my funcions consumes lots of processor time. I have to use progress bar.

```
public int func()
{

for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i ++)
{
  return i;//i need 10 returns of this for broadcast or progressbar.
}
}
```

Comment: In your example, you'll always return 0.

Comment: No, it's not possible. `return` hands control to the method that called the current one.

Comment: You're looking for C#'s `yield return`, which Java does not support.  Consider using `AsyncTask`.

Comment: If i use static i can change the value of variable but this function do not let the other function know if the variable has been changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for calculations behind your GUI. And use [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29)() to send progress. And use [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29)() to send the final result.

If I integrate your example in the android development example it would look like this.

```
new DoMyCalculations(1000);    

private class DoMyCalculations extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
     protected Long doInBackground(Integer... params) {
         int sum = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < params; i++) {
             sum += i;
             publishProgress(i);
         }
         return sum;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress); //a function in your GUI which shows progress
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Sum is: " + result);//a function in your GUI which shows results
     }
 }
```

Comment: I know about it. But now I have very huge logic in other function which is very difficult to paste in async task.

Comment: That huge Logic shouldn't be in your GUI anyway. If it exists in other  created classes you could try to implement Asynctask in them. Nonetheless it's also the correct answer to your question, so please accept it ^^

Comment: but how can I interact AsyncTask in another class and progressbar in main class?

Comment: Ok Im having visitors right now, so i cant finish the example.  You can send an Object containing the activity who calls the asyncTask.  Something like `new DoMyCalculations(new Object[] {this, 1000})`  and your Asynctask =   `private class DoMyCalculations extends AsyncTask<Object[], Integer, Integer> {`  .  onPostExecute can than use the passed Activity to callback. `gui = (MainActivty)params[0]` and gui.taskComplete(result)`

Answer (score 1):

Android provides the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class for this kind of thing. Take a look, in particular, at `onProgressUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for another way.